# how to sum amount for each user?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data like this:

```
 USER_ID   NUM   num_id
1   47641   800    1
2   47641   100    2
3   47641   250    3
4   70919   200    1
5   70919   200    2
6   70919   200    3
7   70919   200    4
```

...

I have no idea what to try, result that i want is this:

```
 USER_ID   NUM   num_id 
1   47641   800    1
2   47641   100    2
3   47641   100    3
4   70919   200    1
5   70919   200    2
6   70919   200    3
7   70919   200    4
...
```

so if for each user, sum of num < 1000 than all num must be same, but if sum of num for each user > 1000 for example for 47641 user we have 800 100 and 250 so we have to sum 800 and 100 and from 250 we need only 100 because 800+100+100=1000 so for num_id=3 we need only 100

I have not written some code...

I only want some ways what to try.
hope you will get idea of problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want the amounts for the first *n* records that sum to 1000.  You want a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       (case when running_sum <= 1000 then num
             when running_sum - num < 1000 then 1000 - (running_sum - num)
             else 0
         end) as new_num
from (select t.*, sum(num) over (partition by user_id order by num_id) as running_sum
      from t
     ) t;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
create table t1(
tuser number,
tnum number,
numid number
);
```

Inserted records :

```
TUSER   TNUM    NUMID
47641   800     1
47641   100     2
47641   300     3
70919   200     1
70919   200     2
70919   200     3
70919   400     4
23451   800     1
23451   100     2
23451   600     3
```

Solution query:

```
select Tuser,
case 
when sum(Tnum) over(partition by Tuser order by numid)<=1000 then Tnum
when sum(Tnum) over(partition by Tuser order by numid)>1000 then 1000-((sum(Tnum) over(partition by Tuser order by numid))-tnum)
end Tnum,numid
from t1;
```

Output:

```
TUSER   TNUM    NUMID
23451   800     1
23451   100     2
23451   100     3
47641   800     1
47641   100     2
47641   100     3
70919   200     1
70919   200     2
70919   200     3
70919   400     4
```

Answer (score -1):

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

/* Create a table called TEST123*/
/* A working example in SQLLITE3*/
 CREATE TABLE TEST123
(USER_ID integer,
NUM integer,
num_id integer);

/* Create few records in this table*/
INSERT INTO TEST123 VALUES(47641,800,1);
INSERT INTO TEST123 VALUES(47641,100,2);
INSERT INTO TEST123 VALUES(47641,250,3);
INSERT INTO TEST123 VALUES(70919,200,1);
INSERT INTO TEST123 VALUES(70919,200,2);
INSERT INTO TEST123 VALUES(70919,200,3);
INSERT INTO TEST123 VALUES(70919,200,4);

/* Display all the records from the table */
SELECT * FROM TEST123;


/*
SELECT a.USER_ID,  a.NUM ,a.num_id , (SELECT SUM(b.NUM) FROM TEST123 AS b where b.num_id<=a.num_id and b.user_id = a.user_id)
FROM TEST123 AS a 
GROUP BY a.USER_ID,a.NUM,a.num_id ORDER BY  a.USER_ID,a.num_id;
*/

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TEMP_TABLE1 AS
SELECT a.USER_ID AS USER_ID,  a.NUM AS NUM ,a.num_id AS num_id, (SELECT SUM(b.NUM) FROM TEST123 AS b where b.num_id<=a.num_id and b.user_id = a.user_id) AS CUM_NUM
FROM TEST123 AS a 
GROUP BY a.USER_ID,a.NUM,a.num_id ORDER BY  a.USER_ID,a.num_id;

SELECT * FROM TEMP_TABLE1;


SELECT USER_ID, NUM, num_id, CASE WHEN CUM_NUM > 1000 THEN (1000 - (CUM_NUM-NUM))  ELSE CUM_NUM END FINAL_CUM_NUM
FROM
TEMP_TABLE1;
```